# xpath for specific code in WebDriverSampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, jmeter

I have a page with a set of fields I need to edit via WebSamplerDriver.
The difficulty is that field id values are not constant and change from time to time.
So, if I use an xpath like `//input[@id='TextField13']`,
it works only very limited time while id is actual.

Code snippet is below:

[image: xpath_question]

I suppose I need to describe xpath for an element with id='TextField13' (which is not a constant) with relevance to the text "First name" (always the same text) in another branch of parent tag (i.e. label).
What is the right way to do that?

Will be appreciated for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
//label[contains(text(),'First name')]//following:://input
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath to select `input` field based on `label` value

```
//label[.="First name"]/following::input
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, probably something is wrong.

Comment: @NadezhdaT how you used it? show code and Exception log

Comment: I'm not sure in syntax. "First name" is a text value, not a class name.

Here is error in a log in connection with locator:
ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Unable to locate element: label[.='First name']/following::input

Comment: @NadezhdaT did you use `label[.='First name']/following::input` or `//label[.='First name']/following::input`?

Comment: Thank you for direction with 'following', I placed the right answer below the question.

Comment: @NadezhdaT your XPath is just slightly modified (more messy) version of mine. Are you sure that my solution didn't work? Note that you don't need extra slash before `/following` and `*//` before `input` is just redundant. Also you don't need to use `contain` function if you want to locate element by **exact text content**

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, but your variant shows error in JMeter log with an error text I placed above.

Comment: @NadezhdaT if real HTML is exactly the same as provided my XPath cannot lead to error. Also you didn't answer whether you used `label...` or `//label...` as according to exception log you've used first option

Comment: I checked as you provided it and shared the log mesage with an error. Syntax is not correct. At the same time, I appreciate your help and tip with "following". xPath works fine in the way I shared it in my answer under this question.